# Search posts by post author name

Tags: posts, search, author

I want to search posts publish by particular author. For this purpose I added a filter in `functions.php`:

```
function wpse_29570_where_filter($where){
        global $wpdb;
        if( is_search() ) {
            $search= get_query_var('s');
            $query=$wpdb->prepare("SELECT $wpdb->users.ID  FROM $wpdb->users WHERE  $wpdb->users.display_name LIKE '%%%s%%' ", $search );
            $authorID= $wpdb->get_var( $query );//die;

            if($authorID){
                $where = "  AND  ( atl_posts.post_author = {$authorID} ) ";
            }
            //echo $where;
         }
         return $where;
    }

    add_filter('posts_where','wpse_29570_where_filter');
```

It I echo the `where` condition it gives

```
AND ( atl_posts.post_author = 1 )
```

but when I search by typing `admin` it shows a blank result.

Please help me to make it work.
Can anyone tell me a better way to do it?

Comment: Two notes: 1) There's `like_query()` to wrap like statements in SQL queries - you need to use that. 2) You will maybe want to intercept on `posts_clauses` hook and _append your custom string to `$where .=` - note the dot.

Comment: @Kaiser i have change it by appending new condition but it is still blank response.

Comment: Have you checked if the `$authorID` brings up the correct ID?

Comment: yeah i checked it it brings up the right id. Please have a look to my issue here t9l.com/sane_voice/?s=making  and when s=admin it filter posts of recent posts but the main post results are blank.

Answer (score 1):

This line is likely the issue -

```
$where = "  AND  ( atl_posts.post_author = {$authorID} ) ";
```

You are replacing the contents of $where, not changing it. You have to use `.` before `=` -

```
$where.= "  AND  ( atl_posts.post_author = {$authorID} ) ";
```

Comment: thanks for your response, i think i miss something else also. can you please have a look at http://t9l.com/sane_voice/?s=making when s=admin or s= hemc it is returning blank response.

Comment: Well I notice that you are checking `display_name`. By default, I believe this is set to the `username`, but if you have edited it at all, then your query would not find an ID for user `admin`. Please check in your admin area under 'Users' and check the display name for the 'admin' account.

Comment: Also, perhaps it would be better to check for both `display_name` and `username` in your code, giving the user the choice of entering either? Don't forget that `display_name` does not have to be unique, where as `username` does.

Comment: query found id for admin i.e 1. i have check it by echo the where condition.

Comment: Ok, so it's finding the ID for admin then. Just out of interest, what is `atl_posts`? Have you changed your table prefix from `wp_` to `atl_`?

Comment: yeah, i have changed the table prefix

Comment: Ok, just checking! Next I'd check to see exactly what query is running, after your posts should be grabbed, add `echo '<pre>'; print_r($wpdb->last_query); echo '</pre>';`. This will tell you what query was passed to MySQL, so you can check that it as it should be. You can also replace `last_query` with `last_result`, which will give you any error that MySQL reported to WP for your query.

Comment: i just realize that it filters the RECENT ARTICLE posts in sidebar but the main content search results are blank.